# What is the maximum access level of class member, if class and member's access modifiers different?

Tags: c#, .net

Trying to find out - is there any difference between:
  public member (property, method) in protected class, and
  protected member (property, method) in public class. It's not only about public and protected. It's about combination of different access modifiers for members of class.

As I understand - class member's maximum allowed access level is the lowest access level of class or member, whichever is lower.

So, public method in protected class will be accessible only within same or derived class. And same access level will be for protected method in public class.
Are my suggestion correct? Or I missing something?

This question came up from C# quiz where it says:
You are creating a class named Employee. The class exposes a string property named EmployeeType.The following code segment defines the Employee class.

```
public class Employee
{
    internal string EmployeeType { get; set; }
}
```

The EmployeeType property value must be accessed and modified only by code within the Employee class or within a class derived from the Employee class.You need to ensure that the implementation of the EmployeeType property meets the requirements. How it must be modified?

I selected:

```
protected string EmployeeType { get; set; }
```

But correct answer was:

```
internal string EmployeeType { protected get; protected set; }
```

So, what is the difference, if in both cases maximum access level of property is protected?

Comment: That "correct answer" won't even compile.

Comment: Whatever quiz you are doing its wrong, id suggest finding another.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ba0a1yw2.aspx

Comment: Now explain what `protected internal` is =p That one gets a lot of people

Comment: your answer is correct

Comment: [link](http://www.elearningexams.com/70-483-dump) Question 17

Comment: It seems that question does not have correct answer at all, because valid option is E but you need to choose *two* options. So just forget about this bad quiz and move on.